# Mongo : count number of array elements for each entry in collection

Tags: java, mongodb, mongodb-query

**Example Date (collection name 'people')**

```
{"person" : "Frank", 
 "coords" : [
    {
        "point":new GLatLng(40.266044,-74.718479), 
    },
    {
        "point":new GLatLng(40.211600,-74.695702),
    }
] }

{"person : ""Bob", 
  "coords" : [
        {
            "point":new GLatLng(40.266044,-74.718479), 
        },
        {
            "point":new GLatLng(40.211600,-74.695702),
        },
        {
            "point":new GLatLng(40.294535,-74.682012),
        }
] }
```

**Goal :** obtain a total number of 'coord' entries for each person document (accumulated overall)

**Expected result 5**

**What I've tried**

```
public int getTotalCoordinateCount(){

  BasicDbObject project= new BasicDBObject()
  .append("count",new BasicDBObject("$size","coords"))

   AggregationOutput output = db.getPeopleCollection().aggregate(Arrays. <DBObject>asList(
     new BasicDBObject("$project", project);

    BasicDbObject result = (BasicDBObject)output.results().iterator.next();

   return result.getInt("count");

}
```

**Problem** I get : 2

Clueless on what I'm doing wrong in the mongo aggregation framework. I suspect i need to include a `$sum` but not sure where

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
public int getTotalCoordinateCount(){

  BasicDbObject group = new BasicDBObject()
  .append("_id", 1)
  .append("count", new BasicDBObject("$sum", 1));

  BasicDbObject project= new BasicDBObject()
  .append("_id", 0)
  .append("count", 1);

   AggregationOutput output = db.getPeopleCollection().aggregate(Arrays. <DBObject>asList(
     new BasicDBObject("$unwind", "coords"),
     new BasicDBObject("$group", group),
     new BasicDBObject("$project", project)
   );

    BasicDbObject result = (BasicDBObject)output.results().iterator.next();

   return result.getInt("count");

}
```

Comment: @serigu Thanks the unwind was the thing that was missing

Answer (score 1):

You need to do an unwind operation on `coords` field, in the aggregation pipeline. After that you do a group by `Null` with a `count` field, to count the results set and you will get the total number of elements from all arrays on all documents.

Comment: can you demonstrate what that would look like? You can keep in JSON format if that makes it easier to produce answer

Comment: I cannot write in Java, but bassically you nee to unwind that list, than you will have x nr of documents as a result, x  is your number.

Comment: see my answer, I try t write it in Java for you.